# How to handle two tables with same repeater using protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have two tables with same repeater : `'campaignSegmentLink in campaign.campaignSegmentLinks'`.
When i use:

```
element.all(by.repeater('campaignSegmentLink in campaign.campaignSegmentLinks'))
```

Protractor always gives back contents of first table.
How can i target the second table? I want the contents of second table not the first.

Comment: You have not shown enough of your code for us to help you

Answer (score 3):

```
element.all(by.repeater('campaignSegmentLink in campaign.campaignSegmentLinks'))
```

would return you all the "repeaters" - from the first and from the second table.

If you want to find rows from a second repeater occurrence, you need to find something unique about it - most likely (you haven't shown the HTML code) it is located in a different container which you can rely on, e.g.:

```
var container = element(by.css("div#myContainer"));  
var rows = container.all(by.repeater('campaignSegmentLink in campaign.campaignSegmentLinks'))
```

Or, you can use [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) to filter out the rows from the second table.

See also:

- [Multiples ng-repeat in the same page](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/278)